# Efficient matrix copying in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I have no idea for how to implement matrix implementation efficiently in OpenCV.
I have binary `Mat nz(150,600)` with 0 and 1 elements.
I have Mat `mk(150,600)` with double values.
I like to implement as in Matlab as

```
sk = mk(nz);
```

That command copy mk to sk only for those element of mk element at the location where nz has 1. Then make sk into a row matrix.
How can I implement it in OpenCV efficiently for speed and memory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should take a look at `Mat::copyTo` and `Mat::clone`.
`copyTo` will make an copy with optional mask where its non-zero elements indicate which matrix elements need to be copied.

```
mk.copyTo(sk, nz);
```

And if you really want a row matrix then call `sk.reshape()` as member **sansuiso** already suggested. This method ...

> creates alternative matrix header for the same data, with different
>   number of channels and/or different number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

bkausbk gave the best answer. However, a second way around:

```
A=bitwise_and(nz,mk);
```

If you access A, you can copy the non-zero into a std::vector. If you want your output to be a cv::Mat instance then you have to allocate the memory first:

```
S=countNonZero(A); //size of the final output matrix
```

Now, fast element access is an actual topic of itself. Google it. Or have a look at opencv/modules/core/src/stat.cpp where `countNonZero()` is implemented to get some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps involved in your task.
First, you convert to double the input matrix:

```
cv::Mat binaryMat;                      // source matrix, filled somewhere
cv::Mat doubleMat;                      // target matrix (with doubles)
binaryMat.convertTo(doubleMat, CV64F);  // Perform the conversion
```

Then, reshape the result as a row matrix:

```
doubleMat = cv::reshape(doubleMat, 1, 1);
// Alternatively:
cv::Mat doubleRow = cv::reshape(doubleMat, 1, 1);
```

The `cv::reshape` operation is efficient in the sense that the data is not copied, only the structure header changes.
This function returns a new reference to a matrix (by creating a new header), thus you should not forget to assign its result.